# Grails: criteria unit testing fails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, criteria, grails-2.0

I'm trying to test the following action:

```
def search = {
    //keep these values so we can rerender on the filters
    def cal=Calendar.getInstance()
    def startCal=Calendar.getInstance()
    def endCal=Calendar.getInstance()
    startCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    startCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    endCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    endCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    startCal.set(params.int('startDate_year')?:Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) -10,params.int('startDate_month')?params.int('startDate_month')-1:Calendar.JANUARY,params.int('startDate_day')?:1)
    def startDate=startCal.getTime()
    endCal.set(params.int('endDate_year')?:Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),params.int('endDate_month')?params.int('endDate_month')-1:cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),params.int('endDate_day')?:cal.get(Calendar.DATE))//cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) cal.get(Calendar.DATE)

    def endDate=endCal.getTime()

    flash.customer = params.customer
    flash.siteName = params.siteName
    flash.review_filter=params.review_filter
    flash.message=""
    flash.startDate=""
    flash.endDate=""
    if(params.startDate_year){
        flash.startDate=startDate
    }
    if(params.endDate_year){        
    flash.endDate=endDate   
    }   
    flash.success_filter=params.success_filter

    //Validation Check


    if(endDate>new Date()|| startDate>new Date()){
        flash.message=message(code: "date.endDate.greaterror")
        render(view:'list',model:[ auditInstanceList: null,auditInstanceTotal:0 ])
        return
    }

    if(startDate>= endDate){
        flash.message=message(code:"date.endDate.aftererror")
        render(view:'list',model:[ auditInstanceList: null,auditInstanceTotal:0 ])
        return

    }

    if(!params.max) {
        params.max = grailsApplication.config.AUDIT_SEARCH_MAX
    }

    def query
    def criteria = Audit.createCriteria()       

    query = {
        and{                
            //between("dateCreated",startDate,endDate)
        //  le("dateCreated",endDate)
            if(params.customer){
                ilike("customerName", params.customer + '%')
            }
            if(params.siteName){
                ilike("siteName", params.siteName + '%')
            }
            max:params.max
            offset:params.offset
            if(startDate){
                ge("dateCreated",startDate)
            }
            if(endDate){
                le("dateCreated",endDate)
            }
            if(params.review_filter=='true' ||params.review_filter=='false'){
                eq("reviewed", params.review_filter=='true' )
            }
            if(params.success_filter=='0'||params.success_filter=='1'){
                eq("success",params.success_filter.toInteger())
            }

        }
    }


    def results = criteria.list(params, query)


    render(view:'list', model:[ auditInstanceList: results,auditInstanceTotal:results.totalCount ])
    [auditInstanceList: results, auditInstanceTotal:results.totalCount]

}
```

I used  @Mock(Audit) annotation but still when I run the test I got null pointer exception. I read that there is problems with criteria testing and grails 2.1.0. This is my Test which fails on the last assertion(It returns null).

```
   def populateValidParams(params) {
    assert params != null
    def now = new Date();
    def byesterday = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()-2);
    println("byesterday"+byesterday)
    params["customerName"] = 'sky'
    params["siteName"] = '123456'
    params["userName"] = 'user'
    params["controllerName"] = 'control'
    params["actionName"] = 'action'
    params["arguments"] = 'arguments'
    params["success"] = 0
    params["msg"] = 'message'
    params["dateCreated"] = byesterday
    params["reviewed"] = false
}

   void testSearch() {

    populateValidParams(params)
    def audit=new Audit(params)
    audit.save(flush:true,failOnError: true)

    def now = new Date();
    def yesterday = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()-1);

    //Search non existing customer
    params.customer='ks'
    params.siteName=''

    controller.search()
    assert model.auditInstanceTotal == 0        

    //Search case insensetive
    params.customer='SK'
    params.siteName=''
    params.endDate_year=''

    controller.search()     
    assert model.auditInstanceTotal == 1

}
```

Any ideas How to solve this?

Comment: Please post stacktrace so it can help investigate.

Comment: didn't get errors but assertions fails.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related to this issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9497

Comment: In description you wrote 'I got null pointer exception', in comment you wrote 'didn't get errors but assertions fails'. Also, you didn't provide your unit test code. I don't know if I can help, but no one can help without more information either.

Comment: At which line are you getting the NPE? Can you provide a full stack trace?